How to use context-path in spring cloud gateway to forward requests?
Have microservice1 to microservice10 , Eureka and Gateway service. All the services registered in Eureka dashboard.
Use following property in gateway to forward requests to corresponding microservice.
**
cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        name : AuthenticationFilter -- <<Globalfilter used>>
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: 'true'
          lower-case-service-id: 'true'

**
Gateway forward requests to correct microservice. Problem arises when using context-path in gateway . Gateway starts with context-path '/api'.
Microservice1 runs fine and has a controller named /hello(returns a string)
Tried calling microservice1( runs on port 9091) through gateway(runs on port 9188) in postman.
http://localhost:9188/api/microservice1/hello - getting 404 status not found error. How to call microservice1 through gateway with context-path /api. Tried adding filters in gateway but erroring out before calling the filter. Can anyone please help me on this?
